# How to get latest GitHub self hosted action runner version inside Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I am trying below code in Dockerfile but I am getting error while I build the Docker image.

```
ENV GITHUB_RUNNER_VERSION=''
RUN $(curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/actions/runner/releases/latest" | jq -r '.tag_name[1:]') >> ${GITHUB_RUNNER_VERSION}


RUN curl -Ls https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/download/v$GITHUB_RUNNER_VERSION/actions-runner-linux-x64-$GITHUB_RUNNER_VERSION.tar.gz | tar zx \
  && chown -R github:github /work \
  && sudo ./bin/installdependencies.sh
```

Error:

```
Step 10/20 : RUN curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/actions/runner/releases/latest" | jq -r '.tag_name[1:]' >> ${GITHUB_RUNNER_VERSION}
 ---> Running in a827248e3eb4
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create : Directory nonexistent
The command '/bin/sh -c curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/actions/runner/releases/latest" | jq -r '.tag_name[1:]' >> ${GITHUB_RUNNER_VERSION}' returned a non-zero code: 2
Error: exit status 2
```

Comment: The reason i am using curl above to fetch version is because github changes the version frequently and that cause issue in the runner

Comment: You seem to be trying to redirect to a file with an empty name when using `>> ${GITHUB_RUNNER_VERSION}`. I guess what you want to do is have the result stored in the variable `GITHUB_RUNNER_VERSION`, but that's not what this command does. Check [this article](https://vsupalov.com/set-dynamic-environment-variable-during-docker-image-build/).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I tried referring to the article u shared.
```
RUN $(curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/actions/runner/releases/latest" | jq -r '.tag_name[1:]') > /root/tmp_variable
RUN GITHUB_RUNNER_VERSION=$(cat /root/tmp_variable);
```
i got this error still:

Step 9/21 : RUN $(curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/actions/runner/releases/latest" | jq -r '.tag_name[1:]') > /root/tmp_variable
 ---> Running in 38bdae63f3b8
/bin/sh: 1: 2.298.2: not found
exit status 127

Comment: It's pretty hard to read code and error messages in content. Please [edit] your question to include your attempt and the output. At first glance it looks like you've got a pointless command subsitution `$(...)` in there. You should have just `some_command > /target/file`. Because `$(some_command) > /target/file` would try to *interpret the output of `some_command` as a command itself and *run* it.

Answer (score 0):

I use a slightly different technique for determining the latest version, but the key to success here is to use an environment variable set in the same `RUN` command that downloads the runner itself:

```
RUN RUNNER_VERSION=$(curl -s "https://github.com/actions/runner/tags/" | grep -Eo "$Version v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+" | sort -r | head -n1 | tr -d ' ' | tr -d 'v') \
    && cd /home/runner \
    && curl -O -L https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/download/v${RUNNER_VERSION}/actions-runner-linux-x64-${RUNNER_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && tar xzf ./actions-runner-linux-x64-${RUNNER_VERSION}.tar.gz
```

You could just use this (noting that it only downloads and decompresses the runner; dependencies are installed in a separate step) or, assuming that everything else in your dockerfile is correct, your command above should work if combined into the single `RUN` statement:

```
RUN GITHUB_RUNNER_VERSION=$(curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/actions/runner/releases/latest" | jq -r '.tag_name[1:]') \
    && curl -Ls https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/download/v${GITHUB_RUNNER_VERSION}/actions-runner-linux-x64-$GITHUB_RUNNER_VERSION.tar.gz | tar zx \
    && chown -R github:github /work \
    && sudo ./bin/installdependencies.sh
```